# How can I get statistics, how line count has changed over time?

Tags: bazaar

How can I get statistics, how line count changed over time? I use bazaar for my project and it would be really nice to know, if I am refactoring code correctly.

Comment: You can get faster answers elsewhere.like on [SO] and [SU]. And may be considered offtopic here since it has nothing to do with ubuntu specifically.

Comment: This isn't off topic at all. In fact, this is a great place to find bazaar users as the Ubuntu project is a heavy user.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [bzr-diffstat](https://launchpad.net/bzr-diffstat):

```
$ bzr diffstat -r 55..57
 foo/bar.py |  2 +-
 po/foo.pot | 56 ++++++++++++++++++---------
 2 files changed, 38 insertions(+), 20 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function for line count statistics.

**But more importantly:** to know if you're refactoring code correctly it is not count statistics you need but unit tests!

If you really want to know how line count changed over time, I think your best bet is write a simple Python program using `bzrlib`, iterate over the revisions, count the lines in each revision and print it out or save in a file or database.

If you still need this and need a code sample, please leave a comment.